# Karate test framework - How to check presence of parameter in response?

Tags: karate

My response (from REST API) can be have an `gg.Errors` array in body.

```
* def tag = response['gg:CreateClientRS']['gg:Errors']['gg:Error']['@Tag'][0];
* ???
* match tag contains "org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException"
```

How to write this part in case without `gg.Errors` array?

**case 1:** no errors => run next step

**case 2:** errors + contains "org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException" => next step

**case 3:** errors + not contains "org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException" => KO

Comment: it would help if you provide a real example.

Comment: @PeterThomas, my sample is a real example

Comment: I meant an example of the response JSON you are trying to work with. but that's fine, someone else here might be able to help, I pass.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not contains `(not) !contains`

```
* match response !contains {gg:Errors}
```

or contains any `match contains any`  [URL](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-contains-any)

```
* def response = ['gg:CreateClientRS']['gg:Errors']['gg:Error']['@Tag'][0]
* match response.gg contains any [ 'CreateClientR', 'Errors', 'Error']
```

For more info check:
/Index /Assert section [URL](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#index)